# Using <h:outputScript> to add javascript code in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to run some basic javascript code with JSF 2.
I'm using the following code to do so:

```
<h:outputScript target="head">
    var props = $.event.props;
</h:outputScript>
```

Looking at the source of the page I can't find any evidence of this code.
I thought that was the correct way to work with javascript code in JSF.
Should I use the `<script>` tag of html instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not the intend purpose of the `outputScript` tag. It just renders an HTML `script` tag while resolving the location of the javascript file that's specified in its `name` attribute.

If you need to inline javascript, just enclose it in the `<script>` tag directly.

Comment: @Ben - it seems you're right, but only in the circumstance of the attribute `name` not being present. From the documentation: `If there is no name attribute and the argument component does have children, the renderer must ensure that those children are encoded as usual.`. Still, it should not be enclosed in the `script` tag...